# How do I apply Linux process limits to processes spawed through Node.js using child_process.spawn

Tags: node.js, linux, security, limit, spawn

I am looking for a way to limit child processes spawned through [child_process.spawn](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options).
The processes are being started as a different user and group. Because the processes are spawned by Node.js, the limits as in [`limits.conf`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/limits.conf) are not applied. I wish to limit how much ram and how many sub-processes are started by the spawned process.
Additionally, the spawned processes may be malicious (hence they are spawned as a different user), and I would prefer to not have to trust them at all, so starting them and using [`prlimit`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/prlimit) is not ideal.
The current code looks something like the following:

```
var cmd = 'mono';
var args = 'script.exe';
var options = {
    uid = user.uid,
    gid = user.gid
};
var newProcess = child_process.spawn(cmd, args, options);
```

}